# jquery ui: slider gallery upgrade problem!

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I am trying to make a slider gallery/ content and I came across this [tutorial](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/) online.

But I think the jquery ui in that tutorial is quite outdated as it is on **jquery-ui-full-1.5.2.min.js**

jquery ui website does not provide this **jquery-ui-full** package anymore - it seems!

So I tried to include the pieces that may need to make that page working with the up-to-date jquery ui.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.ui.slider.js"></script>
```

but it still does not work on my local host. what other pieces have I missed?? does jquery provide all the ui pieces in one js file like **jquery-ui-full-1.5.2.min.js**??

I tried it out on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lauthiamkok/Mk9qC/) - it even worst!

What can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to http://jqueryui.com/, click "Build Custom Download" link. That page contains all jQueryUI components checked. Select version and click "Download".